# Play 2.1, can't access uploaded image until server restarted

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I made a form for uploading images that save files to a play sub-directory `/public/images/`

The images that are saved here, for example `/public/images/test.jpg`, are accessed as something like `http://example.com/assets/images/test.jpg`

The browser indicates this link is broken, until I reset the play server, it then allows me access to recently uploaded images.

When I run the play server in Dev mode using the 'run' command, the images can be uploaded and accessed without doing such a reset.

In `/conf/routes` I have

```
GET        /assets/*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found some info on a Google thread - https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/3_H_YmxzQUo

Apprantly Play isn't designed to do what I described, but I could write my own controller to get it working, to do this I added in `/conf/router`

```
GET     /assets/images/upload/:file_name        controllers.ServeImage.at(file_name)
```

And created `/controllers/ServeImage.java`

```
package controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class ServeImage extends Controller
{
    public static Result at(String filename)
    {
        response().setContentType("image");     
        byte[] i_file = null;

        try
        {
            i_file = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(new File("public/images/upload/"+filename)));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            // return 404
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            // return 404           
        }

        return ok(i_file);
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. Quite surprising that play doesn't make this easy to do. Here is a related controller that serve thumbnails from an external path with the help of the imagescalr lib.

```
package controllers;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.commons.io.output.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;
import play.Play;

import javax.imageio.*;
import static org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

public class ServeThumbnail extends Controller {
    public static Result at(String filename) {
        response().setContentType("image");
        ByteArrayOutputStream img_stream = null;
        try {
            File file = new File(Play.application().configuration().getString("home_dir") + "/pictures/"+filename);
            BufferedImage thumbnail = createThumbnail(ImageIO.read(file));
            img_stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", img_stream);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            return badRequest("image not found");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return badRequest("image not found");
        }
        return ok(img_stream.toByteArray());
    }

    public static BufferedImage createThumbnail(BufferedImage img) {
        img = resize(img, Method.ULTRA_QUALITY, 125, OP_ANTIALIAS, OP_BRIGHTER);
        return pad(img, 4);
    }
}
```